# From node server I couldn't go to another domain

Tags: angularjs, node.js, payment-gateway, mean-stack, payumoney

I am integrating PayUmoney payment gateway to my MEAN stack application. I am getting every mandatory fields from angular controller to node and Hash key also generated. After that I am not redirect to 'https://test.payu.in/_payment'. I have tried like below

### app.js

```
router.post('/buyItem',function(req,res){
    var KEY = "OygoFs";
    var SALT = "BV1QBwCv";

    var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha512'),
        reqData = req.body;
        dataSequence = KEY + '|' + reqData.txnid + '|' + reqData.amount + '|' + reqData.productinfo + '|' + reqData.firstname + '|' + reqData.email + '|||||||||||' + SALT;
        resultKey = shasum.update(dataSequence).digest('hex');
    res.redirect('https://test.payu.in/_payment');
});
```

When I run this error is came.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://locahost:3000/api/buyItem. Redirect from 'http://locahost:3000/api/buyItem' to 'https://test.payu.in/_payment' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to config your redirect url as a whitelist resource to ensure that the URLs used for sourcing Angular templates are safe.

```
app.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider) {
         $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', 'https://test.payu.in/_payment/**']);

}]);
```

From the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider

Answer (score 0):

Your NodeJs-Express cannot send request to payu money until payUmoney itself has authorized you,
That is why you got CORS error,
CORS means- Cross Origin Resource Sharing
That means when you are trying to reach   www.**example1**.com from www.**example2**.com.

So the solution to this problem is that you have to set CORS filter in the PayUmoney server in which you are redirecting to.
You can't just send it to any server or App which is deployed because they always disable CORS filter for security measures.
If you want to check your redirecting feature,
This is what you can do,
make another NodeJs server running which is listening to API calls.
and add these lines in app.js(server-side):

```
    app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
    next();
});
```

**Note**: where app is a reference to express (var app = require('express');).

Now redirect to this Newly created NodeJs app,
Your redirect feature will definitely work.

Hope this helps,
Regards
Shohil

Comment: I have added above line in my node server but its not working

Comment: you don;t have to add it in your server,
It has to be added to the Server to which you are sending request.
This code is to accept cross-origin from any server, only for testing purpose.

Comment: @Kevin
Try to understand,
CORS is configured where you want your requested to be received successfully. And not in from the sending source.
That is the reason why i said,

Comment: If you are trying to test the redirect feature, Then inspite of sending request to payUmoney send it to a new Localhost NodeJs-Express application in which the code ii gave you needs to be inserted.
Hope it helps,
Thank you
Regards
Shohil

Comment: You must me getting this error with status code: 405 which means FORBIDDEN
This is because payUmoney doesn't recognize your server side request and throws CORS error.

Comment: Hope it helps,
Enjoy coding
Regards 
Shohil

Comment: Thanks for your help.